# Rendering vector-tiles using Mapbox using react-mapbox-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, vector-tiles

I have a geoJSON file that I convert into `vector.tiles` using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-vt). 
I use `const tileIndex = geojsonvt(geoJSON)`. The geoJSON file has the following format and it gets converted without any error.

```js
const geoJSON = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  crs: {
    type: 'name',
    properties: { name: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84' }
  },
  features: [
    {
      properties: [Object],
      geometry: [Object],
      type: 'Feature',
      _id: '5ed7b221a61a4b2970433932'
    },
    ... 1840 more items
 ]
}
```

The result (geoJSON vector-tiles) that I get after conversion is following -

```js
const tiles = {
    options: {},
    tiles: {
      '0': {
        features: [Array],
        numPoints: 540529,
        numSimplified: 3,
        numFeatures: 1940,
        source: null,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        transformed: false,
        minX: 0.5162953202777778,
        minY: 0.316725863688461,
        maxX: 0.5338655772222223,
        maxY: 0.34955196703359503
      },
      '1': { ... } 
    },
    tileCoords: [
        { z: 0, x: 0, y: 0 },   { z: 1, x: 1, y: 1 },
        { z: 1, x: 1, y: 0 },   { z: 2, x: 3, y: 1 },
        { z: 2, x: 3, y: 0 },   { z: 2, x: 2, y: 1 },
        { z: 3, x: 5, y: 3 },   { z: 3, x: 5, y: 2 },
        { z: 3, x: 4, y: 3 },   { z: 3, x: 4, y: 2 },
        { z: 4, x: 9, y: 5 },   { z: 4, x: 9, y: 4 },
        { z: 4, x: 8, y: 5 },   { z: 5, x: 17, y: 11 },
        { z: 5, x: 17, y: 10 }, { z: 5, x: 16, y: 11 },
        { z: 5, x: 16, y: 10 }, { z: 4, x: 8, y: 4 },
        { z: 2, x: 2, y: 0 },   { z: 1, x: 0, y: 1 },
        { z: 1, x: 0, y: 0 }
      ]
}
```

After converting a huge geoJSON file with 5000 layers into vector tiles, I am sending this data to the client-side wherein I render **Map** using **React.js** and **Mapbox***. I use following to render the map but I have not been able to figure out what I am doing wrong. The error that I get says `error: layers.jsx-layer-0: layer "jsx-layer-0" must specify a "source-layer"`

```js
<Source type="vector" tiles={data.tiles} >
  <Layer  {...dataLayer}/>
</Source>
```

I went through the documentation of Mapbox for the same but I'm unable to find what I am doing wrong. Any help would be of great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: share your layers json?  and little bit of your react js code. Meaning here is in your layers you need define source layer.  example your layers in json like  "layers": [
  {
    "id": "rivers",
    "source": "my-source",
    "source-layer": "waterway",
    "type": "line",
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "#FFC0CB"
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

react-mapbox-gl is in many places just a wrapper around mapbox-gl, and if you look at the documentation there:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#tiled-sources

You will see that the "tiles" property is only for url sources, where as the "url" property can be used to load a file with tiles:

"url": "http://api.example.com/tilejson.json"

Answer (score -1):

The docs indicate that the `source-layer` is [required field](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#source-layer) for vector layers.

That said, it certainly opaque as to how this works in a declarative api. Based on [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/), you might try this to see if it works -

```
...
const url = 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2' 
const source = 'my-source';

<Source id={{source}} name={{source}} type="vector" url={url} tiles={data.tiles} >
    <Layer source={{source}} {...dataLayer}/>
</Source>
...
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this does not work. 
I have an error - ```Error: layers.jsx-layer-0.source-layer: string expected, object found```.

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately I don't have access to a project, so I am guessing from the docs. I updated with another variation to try, if that is of interest. Otherwise, hope you get it sorted!

Answer (score -1):

rendering a layer with it source so you need to referrer to source id in layer + you need to add a source-layer prop like this:

```
  <Source id='contours' type='vector' url='mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2' tileJsonSource={data.tiles}/>
  <Layer
    id='contours'
    type='line'
    source='contours'
    source-layer='contour'
    paint={{
      'line-color': '#877b59',
      'line-width': 1
    }}
  />
</MapGL>;
```

Comment: where are you rendering tiles dataset on the map ?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't mention that here, try to pass data to `tileJsonSource` prop, and can you tell me which react map gl you are using ?

Comment: It is a bit unclear. Can you edit the code above? Thaks

Comment: edited. just try adding  tiles dataset to `tileJsonSource` prop in Source component.

Comment: I tried your solution - but it does not work. I get following error - ```Unable to update <Source> prop: tileJsonSource```